# Get Payment dates in a list

Tags: arraylist, java-8, payment, java-time, localdate

I have a payment check application, in that I get 2 strings:

```
String contractBegin = "01-01-2018";
String contractEnd = "31-12-2018";
```

Now every payment must be done the last Friday of the month. I need to calculate those dates and place it in a list or array.

Is there any optimal way to do that using the Java 8 nice features?

I started here:

```
    String contractBegin = "01-01-2018";
    String contractEnd = "31-12-2018";

    LocalDate contractStart = LocalDate.parse(contractBegin, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
    LocalDate contractStop = LocalDate.parse(contractEnd, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
    System.out.println(contractStart);
    System.out.println(contractStop);
    List<LocalDate> payCheck= new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        payCheck.add(...) ??
    }
```

Comment: need some clarification. What's args ?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about your ***args*** array. But If you want to get every last friday of month between the contract start and end date. I would do as follow :

```
    String contractBegin = "01-01-2018";
    String contractEnd = "31-12-2018";

    LocalDate contractStart = LocalDate.parse(contractBegin, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
    LocalDate contractStop = LocalDate.parse(contractEnd, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));

    List<LocalDate> payCheck = new ArrayList<>();
    LocalDate payCheckDate = contractStart;

    while (payCheckDate.isBefore(contractStop)) {
        payCheckDate = payCheckDate
                .with(lastDayOfMonth())
                .with(previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
        payCheck.add(payCheckDate);
        payCheckDate = payCheckDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextMonth());

    }

    payCheck.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This gives you every last friday of each month.

Comment: I think it's better to use `previousOrSame` (otherwise it won't work if the last day of month is a Friday)

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to [@gnostrenoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44433736/7605325) is to use `TemporalAdjusters.lastInMonth()` method, which gives you the specified last day of week in the month:

```
// get the last Friday of the month
payCheckDate = payCheckDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastInMonth(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
```

The rest of the `while` loop is the same as [@gnostrenoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44433736/7605325).